# How do I detect an entity with a certain name and replace it with a multi-block structure?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm building a map in which the player needs to take a raft. The player is meant to place down a birch boat named "Raft" and when it's placed down, the boat is removed and replaced with an actual raft made of yellow wool. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Or is this a "do my project for me" question?

Comment: I have tried using scoreboards, but I can't figure out how to get the coordinates of the entity and place a block there. Also, please stop being so conclusive.

Comment: "conclusive"? How can that word describe a person? Anyway, saying "I tried using scoreboards" is like answering "a black one" to the question what computer you have. It's not wrong, but also not helpful. Scoreboards are a tool, not a plan or a solution on their own. What is your plan? What have you researched, tried, considered, …? I recommend reading the [tour] and a bit of the [help center], where it says that askers are supposed to put effort into their question, for example reducing their problem to exactly the thing they have problems with and what they tried so far.

Comment: I figured it out. I used testfor, execute, and clone commands. It's not flawless, but it works nicely. It took me several hours of research and work, before and after your message, but I'm happy with the result that I fully came up with, without asking someone to "do my project for me." Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then you can write an answer, that way people in the future can find it if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this task possible you will need two command blocks in a chain. The first one repeating always active and the second one chain always active and conditional.

The first command block could be “redstone active” or “always active” it will be set to repeating meaning it will happen 20 times every second or once every .05 seconds. Next put it on unconditional because there is no command block before it. Write the command `/execute @e[type=boat,name=raft] ~ ~ ~ fill ~5 ~ ~5 ~-5 ~ ~-5 wool 4`

The second command block could be both as well but must be powered when the top one is and vise versa. As for command block type it must be chain so it will activate after the repeating command block if powered. Last setting is the “conditional/unconditional” turn it to conditional so it will only work if the first one works. Set the command to `/kill @e[type=boat,name=raft]`

> SUMMARY: First command block find “raft” and makes a 5 by 5 platform of yellow wool. Second command kills the “raft(s)” found.